# DLL – static vector which is filled up at DLL’s initialization time, returns zero size to the client program

Tags: c++, vector, dll

I am experiencing the following issue, in my DLL project:

At the DLL side :

- Inside the DLL I have declared a static vector as follows :

  ```
  static std::vector<FilterProcessor::FilterInfo*> TableOfContents;
  ```
- At DLL’s initialization time of static members, I am adding some entries to the above vector.
- I have defined an extern “C” global function (getTocPointer())  which is returning a pointer to the vector, when it  called from the client program.

  ```
  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<FilterProcessor::FilterInfo*>*  __cdecl getLibraryTOC();
  ```

At the client’s program side :

- The DLL library is loaded without any problem
- The address of `getTocPointer()` function is returned correctly to the client program, when the `getProcAddress()` function is called.
- Indeed, when I am performing the debugging process in the DLL-side, the client program calls the above function and the execution process enters to it.
- However, the vector has a zero size and, has no any contents which were added to it at initialization time. It seems it points to another vector object. . .

I can’t really understand what exactly goes wrong here.

The way of adding entries to this vector at initialization time, is the proper way?

If yes, what probably goes wrong when the client program calls the getLibraryTOC() function?

Thanks in advance

George

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: when u say `at DLL's initialization time of static members' what is you mean? you need to post the code and context of when you initialize the vector.

Comment: Once you fix this problem, you're going to run into much harder problems with sharing standard library objects across a DLL boundary.  If both compilers don't agree on the memory layout of the object, the allocator, etc, then you will have trouble.

Comment: Οκ, the problem was resolved as follows:
- I used the Ben Voigt's recommendation about static table_Of_Contents variable, in order to avoid SIOF.

- I used a template class according to CRT pattern, in order to have only one filter_Info static mebmer for each derived class.
At this time everything seems to work fine.
Thanks a lot all of you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that static global definition of the vector appears in a header file, then yes you do have multiple different vectors.  Change the keyword `static` to `extern` to make the header file *declare* the vector rather than defining it, and then add exactly one definition in an implementation file.

Then, you may encounter the static initialization order fiasco.  If the `vector` is defined in a different compilation unit than the code attempting to add entries to it, there's no guarantee that the `vector` object is alive yet.  Attempting to use a `vector` whose constructor hasn't run is undefined behavior -- it might easily manifest as the constructor running afterward and setting the contents to zero length (as a default constructor should), but many other problems are possible.

You can avoid the SIOF by using a local static.

```
std::vector<FilterProcessor::FilterInfo*>& table_of_contents()
{
    static std::vector<FilterProcessor::FilterInfo*> singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

In every location that would have accessed the global, including the initialization logic that fills the vector, and also your `getLibraryTOC()` exported function, call the accessor function instead.

That all is applicable to any C++ software having multiple compilation units.  When you have a DLL, things get even more complicated, because the DLL and EXE are compiled and linked separately from each other, possibly with different settings, different compilers, or even entirely different languages.  Sharing of complex objects across DLL boundaries is real trouble.  If the DLL and EXE are always recompiled at the same time, it can work.  But if you're trying to distribute the DLL for use by another party who writes the EXE code, the strong coupling will quickly become intolerable.

A better approach is to hide the library objects from the DLL boundary, and pass only primitive or OS-managed types across.  For example:

```
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl

extern "C" DLLAPI int32_t getLibraryTocCount()
{ return table_of_contents.size(); }

extern "C" DLLAPI BSTR getLibraryTocName(int index)
{ return ::SysAllocString(table_of_contents[index].name.c_str(); } // assumes std::wstring

// etc
```

Comment: I tried to use a local static, according to your suggestion, but at the end of initialization phase of all filter statics, the table of contents contains the value of last entry added to it, in all its entries.

Comment: @GeorgetheXrousaios: Because you are storing pointers in your vector, adding an item doesn't make a copy.  If the object you added is then destroyed, the vector is left with a bad pointer.  Be very careful when taking the address of a local variable, the resulting pointer is no good after the local variable leaves scope.

Answer (score 0):

The library I have implemented contains the following code (in a brief description) :

- An Index class which implements the Table of contents of the library
- A collection of audio filters named Filter01, Filter02 etc.

**Index.h**

```
struct LIB_SPECS Library_TableOfContents
{
    static  bool addTOCEntry(FilterInfo* Filter_Info);   // add an entry to the TOC
    static std::vector<FilterInfo*> TableOfContents;     // TOC 
};

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------
  Called from the client program to return the pointer to TOC     */

  extern "C" LIB_SPECS std::vector<FlterInfo*>*  __cdecl getLibraryTOC();
```

**Index.cpp**

```
/* Define / Initialize static variables */
std::vector<FilterInfo*> Library_TableOfContents::TableOfContents = {};

//=====================================================================
bool Library_TableOfContents::addTOCEntry(FilterInfo* Filter_Info)
{  
   Library_TableOfContents::TableOfContents.push_back(Filter_Info);
   return false;
}
//======================================================================
std::vector<FilterInfo*>* getLibraryTOC()
{
   return &Library_TableOfContents::TableOfContents;
}
```

For each Audio Filter in the library :

**Filterxx.h**

```
class LIB_SPECS Filterxx
{
public:
    static struct FilterInfo
    {
    public:
        std::string filterName;
        std::string filterDescription;
        // other filter info
        FilterInfo();                   // FilterInfo constructor
    } Filter_Info;

    virtual String doSomeWork(int AvatarId);
    virtual void deleteFilter() = 0;

};
```

**Filterxx.cpp**

```
Filterxx::FilterInfo Filterxx::Filter_Info("Filterxx", “A filter description e.g. Low pass Filter ” );   //  

FilterInfo::FilterInfo(std::string name, std::string description)
{
   Filter_Info.filterName = name;
   Filter_Info.filterDescription = description;
   Library_TableOfContents::addTOCEntry(&Filter_Info);
}

// other filter functions
```

The getLibraryTOC() function, is called from the client program to get the table of contents in order to show it to the user. 
As I said, indeed it is called by the client but, at the time of call, the table of contents seems to have a zero size.

Comment: That `static struct FilterInfo FilterInfo`... there's only one of them, you take the address of the same object many times.  At least it isn't a local variable that gets destroyed, ... but it is getting overwritten.  It is very unusual for a constructor to copy the arguments into a *different* instance of the class, instead of the object being created.

Comment: @BenVoigt : In the file-names "Filterxx.h" and "Filterxx.cpp", the -xx- stands for -01-, -02-, etc.. . So, each static struct FilterInfo belongs to a particular class only.